# docker - unable to change directory of volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have had no luck with searching for a solution to this.

I have 2 docker containers. `frontend`, and `api`. Both need a folder and its contents `models` to build.
All of these files live in a folder named Website, so the tree would look like:

```
Website:
 -models
 -api
   -dockerfile
 -frontend
   -dockerfile
 -docker-compose.yml
```

I am very new to docker, and believe this is how this should be setup, my `dockerfile` inside of the api directory is like so:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/models
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./api/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./api/ /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This results in 2 `models` folders being created in side of the docker container, one containing no files located at path (this is where I want my contents):

```
root@0aa4496c9077:/usr/src/app/models#
```

and another folder that contains the content that I want it to have, however it is located at:

```
root@0aa4496c9077:/usr/src/app/src/models#
```

My question is: how do I map the folder and contents from the Website directory, to the docker container directory `/usr/src/app/models`?

my actual docker-compose.yml file is as so:

```
version: "3"

services:
    api:
        container_name: api
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./api/dockerfile
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
            - "3001:3001"
        volumes:
            - ./models:./models
        links:
            - mongo
```

I have attempted changing the volumes path to be absolute, such as:

```
volumes:
  - $PWD/models:/usr/src/app/models
```

with no luck :(

The build output of running `docker-compose build` is:

```
mongo uses an image, skipping
Building api
Step 1/8 : FROM node:latest
latest: Pulling from library/node
Digest: sha256:521df806339e2e60dfdee6e00e75656e69798c141bd2cff88c0c9a9c50ad4de5
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:latest
 ---> 4495f296c63b
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 94f87a509559
Step 3/8 : COPY ./api/package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3c2e8c17ebf5
Step 4/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 90dc7d21af18
Step 5/8 : COPY ./api/ /usr/src/app
 ---> 5fa3a2b219ef
Step 6/8 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 6ad5fbea1ed8
Removing intermediate container 6ad5fbea1ed8
 ---> b2f8f2f9129c
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 3001
 ---> Running in 2342665c8da3
Removing intermediate container 2342665c8da3
 ---> 9f1162670b55
Step 8/8 : CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
 ---> Running in fc9d766bd5c1
Removing intermediate container fc9d766bd5c1
 ---> a7267b99b3c2
Successfully built a7267b99b3c2
Successfully tagged website_api:latest
```

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Is the site directory in the host OS/machine?

Comment: the website directory is on the host, and it is not in the container. that part is correct

Comment: Waht version of Docker compose are you using?

Comment: Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
And the host is Linux and so is the container

Comment: Can you `COPY` it into the image, the same way you `COPY ./api` in?  Nothing you show obviously looks like that content should be in the image at all, unless there's an additional copy on your host in `website/api/src/models`.

Comment: The reason why I haven't used COPY is because I would have to rebuild the container every time I update the content in the models folder. As I understand it, the dockerfile only runs on build, and the docker-compose is what will run again every time I start or restart the container

Answer (score 0):

Use `./models:./models` without `$PWD` , and it's supposed to work.

`./models`is interpreted as relative to the location of the Compose file.

No need to supply absolute path, just relative path and docker-compose will figure it out.

Comment: Sadly, the models remain in the /usr/src/app/src/models directory, Removing $PWD seems to have no change. I have added the build output to my original question and updated to remove pwd. Thank you very much for the help.... I really wanna get this figured out!

Comment: Check premssions, who can do what, where? Syntax looks okay, not sure what else can be the culprit..

Comment: so, I have found that: docker run -it --mount src="$(pwd)/models",target=/usr/src/models,type=bind website_api
Works PERFECTLY!!!
But I can't figure out how to get that into my docker-config :'(